# Is it possible to convert many if/else statements to a dictionary for space efficiency?

Tags: javascript

In Javascript is it possible to convert many if/else statements to a dictionary for space efficiency?

For example I have the following which is longer in reality

```
if (namelen < 20) {
form.innerHTML = 'hurray!';
}
else if (namelen > 20 && lastname < 90) {
form.innerHTML = 'too long';
}
else if (namelen > 90 && lastname < 120) {
form.innerHTML = 'go away you cheater';
}
...
```

Is there a way to make that into a dictionary for space efficiency?

maybe something like

```
var diction = {namelen < 20: 'hurray', namelen > 20: 'too long', lastname < 90: 'too long', namelen > 90: 'go away you cheater', namelen < 120: 'go away you cheater'}
```

If not a dictionary, how would I refactor that many if else? bear in mind that I'm new to JS and can have missed some important features, and before you ask I spend most of the day reading programming books and the rest of the day coding.

Comment: You can use `switch` https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/switch#Example:_Using_switch.

Comment: @DOCASAREL It would still be long and I have like hundred of them. I'm looking for a compacter way. Other than that how can you use a switch with comparison ops?

Comment: @DOCASAREL In this question you can clearly see that switch is only for checking single variables, not comparison ops or exps http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3575825/convert-from-if-else-to-switch-statement

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try something like this:

```
var dict = [
    { max: 0 },
    { max: 20,  str: 'hurray!' },
    { max: 90,  str: 'too long' },
    { max: 120, str: 'go away you cheater' }
];
for(var i = 1; i < dict.length; i++){
    if(namelen > dict[i-1].max && lastname < dict[i].max){
        form.innerHTML = dict[i].str;
    }
}
```

So, if `namelen` is greater than the "previous `max`", and lastname is less than `max`, set the `innerHTML`.

Notice that I initialized my `i` as `1`, so the for loop will start looking at `dict[1]`. This way, I can use that first object in to make `namelen > dict[i-1]` work.

Comment: heh! Didn't think about putting dicts inside an array. That's a clever idea Cerbrus :-)

Comment: Often, an array of objects is easier to iterate over than just a plain object with a lot of properties.

Comment: It works and I also optimized the inner loop a bit to avoid performance penalties. Thank you for giving me a base where I can build upon. Cheers!