# Search for Values in Array

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to check if there are some specific values are contained in a array. I could wirte is like this:

```
if($.inArray('Z', arr) != -1){
  ..
}else if($.inArray('A', arr) != -1){
  ..
}else if($.inArray('G', arr) != -1){
  ..
}else if($.inArray('T', arr) != -1){
......
```

Or shorter like that:

```
if($.inArray('Z', arr) != -1) || ($.inArray('A', arr) != -1) || ($.inArray('G', arr) != -1) ||($.inArray('T', arr) != -1) ... {
```

But is there a even shorter version of my code? Thanks

Comment: Perhaps here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25658681/is-it-possible-to-convert-many-if-else-statements-to-a-dictionary-for-space-effi?noredirect=1#comment40095937_25658681.

Comment: Use `in_array()` function...

Answer (score 8):

You can use [`Array.prototype.some`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) to iterate over an array and check if any element in the array matches a given predicate:

```
var found = arr.some(function(s) {
    return s.match(/^[ZAGT]$/);
});
```

If you don't watch to use a regexp, replace the middle line with:

```
return s === 'Z' || s === 'A' || s === 'G' || s === 'T';
```

The nice feature of `.some` is that it'll break out of its internal loop as soon as any match is found.

Comment: How is the browser support for some() ?

Comment: @DesignbyAdrian all modern browsers, and trivially shimmable (code at the posted link) on older browsers.

Answer (score 3):

You can add a prototype function and work this with a loop:

```
Array.prototype.any = function(items)
{
    for(var i = 0 ; i < items.length ; i++)
    {
        if(this.indexOf(items[i]) != -1)
            return true;
    }

    return false;
}

var arr = [1,2,34,5,6];
console.log(arr.any([3,15])); // false
console.log(arr.any([3,5])); // true
```

Comment: seriously, adding a jQuery dependency to an `Array` prototype function?!

Comment: @Alnitak - Your'e right..I used his example and took the $.inArray from there..

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to find an element in an array to check if it's there you could use the indexOf javascript function.

`arr.indexOf("A")`

This of course will return the index of the element "A" if contained and -1 if not contained.

Maybe I misunderstood :)